# COUNT on Sub Query and Join

Tags: sql

Guys I am trying to use COUNT on two different SQL statements. One is using joins and the other one is using sub queries. But the problem is, both are displaying different number of rows. 
Why is that?

Query 1 :

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS 'Count',
        (SELECT c.CustomerName 
         FROM dbo.tblCustomer c 
         WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID) AS 'CustomerName',
        (SELECT ProductName 
         FROM dbo.tblProduct p 
         WHERE o.ProductID = p.ProductID) AS 'ProductName'
FROM dbo.tblOrder o
WHERE (o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-5-15' AND '2014-5-20')
GROUP BY o.CustomerID, o.ProductID
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS 'Count', 
        dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerName, 
        dbo.tblProduct.ProductName
FROM dbo.tblCustomer 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblOrder ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblOrder.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProduct ON dbo.tblOrder.ProductID = dbo.tblProduct.ProductID
WHERE (dbo.tblOrder.OrderDate BETWEEN '2014-5-15' AND '2014-5-20')
GROUP BY CustomerName,ProductName
```

Both queries are same in nature except one is using JOINs while the other one is using sub queries. Then why am I getting different number of rows in return?

Comment: Are all your customer names and product names unique?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Barmar No, all customer names and product names are not similar. That is why I want to count all the products and customers that are similar in order. 
For example, if Alex has bought Iphone 5s three different times, I want to display it one time with count as '3'

Comment: I think the problem is that your 2 subqueries are not JOINED.In the second query you make the first JOIN and on the resulting set you make the second JOIN.

Comment: @Mihai That's normal. There's nothing about customers in the Product table, and vice versa. They both only need to be joined with Order.

Comment: I also forgot to mention, result displayed by the JOIN statement is correct. Sub query one is showing additional rows.

Comment: as main table in 1 query you using tblOrder table, in 2 query you using tblCustomer table. I'm guessing that in order table there are many records with the same customer and product...

Comment: I guess the reason when the first query shows more rows - you have got deleted rows in `tblCustomer`  or  in `tblProduct` so in the first query there are broken links to these tables. Check the first query if there are NULLs in `CustomerName` or `ProductName` subqueries results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query you group by ids, in the second by names. So the first query gives you counts per customer and product, whereas the second query gives you counts per equally named customers and equally named products.

**Example:**

```
user 1 = John, user 2 = John
product a = toy, product b = toy
orders: 1 a, 1 a, 1 b, 2 a
```

**query 1:**

```
2, John, toy
1, John, toy
1, John, toy
```

**query 2:**

```
4, John, toy
```

Comment: How stupid of me..Thank you for putting it so nicely. Btw if I want the result that is similar to Query 2 result but by using only sub queries then how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `SELECT CustomerName, ProductName, SUM("Count") FROM (query 1 here) GROUP BY CustomerName, ProductName;`

Comment: Have you taken this statement and pasted in yours? Maybe it's because of the quotes around the names. You used ' which should only be used with string literals, not names. I used ". Different dbms handle this differently. It would be best not to use any quotes and not to use reserved words like Count for a name at all.

Comment: I see. Well I tried ' and " and without quotes but the result is the same and yes, I entered the query 1. The error is "Incorrect Syntax" near GROUP.

Comment: What dbms are you using? Some dbms require a name for the inner query, for instance: `SELECT CustomerName, ProductName, SUM("Count") FROM (query 1 here) tmp GROUP BY CustomerName, ProductName;`

Comment: unfortunately it does not.

Comment: Now that you removed all quotes, avoided reserved words and named the subquery, I don't know what the problem may be. Maybe just some typo in your query. Here is an SQL fiddle and it doesn't have any syntax error: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b825/1 .

Comment: Awesome! there was a problem at my end. Just resolved it. It is executing now. But there is a slight problem, Query 2 displays 286 rows while this query displays 284 rows. 2 rows difference.

Comment: Use EXCEPT to find the difference in the results. Then think about why These two records appear in one result and not in the other. `query2 EXCEPT thisquery`.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Barnipedgar' to data type int. This is what I get. "Barnipedgar" is the product name. why is this query trying to convert it into 'int'?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Or do the column sequences differ? Make sure you select count, customer name and product name in the same sequence in both queries (not *cnt, cname, pname* in one query and *cname, pname, cnt* in the other).

Comment: Ahh, that was it. Thank you brother for sticking with me and helping me out. I really appreciate your help. Stay blessed.